# Add a notification when one of your questions get a status-* tag

Tags: feature-request

So you can follow up your suggestions (or solutions to bugs) like we could in uservoice

Comment: Isn't the generic notification system already doing it some way?

Comment: Not as far as I can tell - I've had a few tagged and it's not come up. I think it's because it's classed as an edit.

Comment: is there a way to see if a tag was added to your question?

Comment: you can check the "revisions" tab under your recent activity, although there is a bug in it (see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4914/revisions-tab-in-recent-activity-is-based-on-date-question-was-posted-not-on-dat).  basically, a revision to a post you made last week will only show up when you click the "last week" link, even if the revision was made nine minutes ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will already get notified via the envelope when your questions are edited, and that counts as an edit.

Comment: The envelope is just a generic "something happened".  All edits should receive more prominent notifications.  **IMO** edits are just as important as answers/comments.

Comment: The current bounty reason states this answer is out of date, when it really isn't. When your question is retagged/edited, you get a notification. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @Gaffi The notification system has changed many times since 03/2010. Recently when [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128331/148672) was marked with status-complete I was given no notification. Have you had a different experience?

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter Yes, the system has changed, but I can still see the details on [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/148672/some-helpful-commenter?tab=responses&sort=revisions&StartDate=2012-09-04%2016:33:18Z) (adapted for your user info based on my own), and I do recall seeing the notification in the super collider for [this question of mine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144383/bounty-notice-for-bounty-offered-by-deleted-banned-user-has-blank-username).

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter Mind you, it's not some *special* notification highlighting the red tags, so if that's what you're looking for, I'll concede.

Comment: @Gaffi that is what I'm looking for. In the Notification Tab on the collider. I guess similar to the way I get one for suggested edits. But again only for the red moderator tags.