# The word "Constructor" in results can break the grid in Data Explorer

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

Queries like

`SELECT 1, 'constructor', 1`

or

```
SELECT  id, tagname, count
FROM tags where id = 1531
```

[See this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/66050/whats-up-with-the-constructor-tag)

or

`SELECT * FROM TAGS`

Don't work in the results to grid mode,  but do in "Text-Only Results"

The following however all work fine

```
SELECT 1, 'constructor'
SELECT 1, 'constructor' , 1 , 1
SELECT 1 , 1, 'constructor' 
SELECT 1, 'constructor' , 'A'
SELECT 'A', 'constructor' , 1
```

If it matters I'm using Chrome 18.0.1025.142

Comment: Probably some JavaScript going wrong, the `constructor` property is special.

Comment: @lunboks no doubt. Interestingly its the combination `number,'constructor', number` that make it break.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[lunboks was correct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128331/the-word-constructor-in-results-can-break-the-grid-in-data-explorer#comment350160_128331), the issue was related to the JavaScript attempting to access the `constructor` property because of the name of the value.

It only happened in some of your examples because the number, string, number result set was recognised by the graphing code as something it should attempt to unpivot and plot. When the unpivoted string value was a reserved property, that caused some problems in the graph code - the exception from which also prevented the SlickGrid rendering from occurring.

I checked in a fix to [prefix the name used](http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-sede/source/detail?r=82759fdb5edc150ef4e1738e5a6f93b146cea23c) to avoid collisions like this in the future, pending a pull and deploy from waffles.

Comment: So it was two separate bugs?

Comment: Nah, just that the table code never ran because the graphing code threw an exception before that could happen. As long as the graphing code no longer throws an exception, everything's fine.

Comment: Then what do you mean by `It only happened in some of your examples`

Comment: Ah, perhaps that was poor wording on my part. I was explaining that the difference between the first three queries in your question and the last five was that the first three all triggered the graphing code which was responsible for the bug.