# Activity log entry before registration date

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, recent-activity

I noticed a strange entry in my activity log at Stack Overflow. The first one:

[image: predated activity]

This is 2011. The funny thing is: I never did that. Even funnier: I registered at SO somewhere in July. In September, I did a tiny revision though:

[image: real activity]

So, where does the first entry come from? Is it a bug?

I don't know if [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4914/revisions-tab-in-recent-activity-is-based-on-date-question-was-posted-not-on-da) is related. maybe the developer in question has recently been set free?

Comment: That, or you will invent time travel in the future.

Comment: I already did, next week.

Comment: then leave notes to your past self so it doesn't get confused. Look, it's already asked a question about it on Meta Stack Overflow! Be a bit more considerate to yourself.

Comment: I don't believe you about next week, by the way. Look at your current situation. Are you going to discover time travel during the next seven days? Hardly likely, is it? The way I see it it's still 10-15 years into the future. Unless your future self in 10-15 years starts messing around time and space, and sends your future self in seven days the blueprints. But that would be *terribly* dangerous.

Comment: Yeah, the Swiss neutrino made me a bit overconfident.

Comment: Please be more careful in the future. Well, and in the past and present too, obviously.

Comment: I'm seeing the same bug.  The oldest entry in my activity log is "created ada description", dated 2010-08-30 (nearly a year before I registered), but my only actual activity shown in the [tag:ada] tag wiki's history is a suggested edit on 2012-01-17.  The wiki was created on 2010-08-30, but not by me.  I see the same thing for at least one other tag wiki I edited ([tag:rcs]).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have been battling the activity stream tag wiki stuff for a while now, for example: [Tag wiki edits are missing in the activity profile tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98380/tag-wiki-edits-are-missing-in-the-activity-profile-tab)

Initially when I designed tag wikis "community user" created the wiki blank and then the end user "revised" the blank wiki. Some people found this confusing so we changed it so the initial revision is a "proper" creation revision however the post is owned by community.

Trouble is this design makes querying for activity very very annoying. We cache an entry in our Posts table for `LastEditorUserId`, however have no cached entry for `FirstEditorUserId`.

There was a bug there that used `LastEditorUserId` as though it was `FirstEditorUserId`.

I amended the query to properly join into `PostHistory` to figure out the proper timeline.

Apologies for the confusion.