# According to the activity tab of my profile, I performed some actions on a site before joining

Tags: bug, profile-page, tag-wiki, recent-activity

If you go to the [last page of the activity tab of my profile on Anime.SE](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/1908/senshin?tab=activity&sort=all&page=151) (you may need to go back a few more pages if I perform more activities later), you will see that I apparently created some tag-wiki descriptions on 8 Feb 2013 and 11 Feb 2013.

[image]

However, my profile on that site was only created on 17 June 2013.

[image]

[The revision history of the "manga-production" tag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/posts/2388/revisions) reveals that the tag was initialized (empty) by Community on 8 Feb 2013 and that I made the first edit to it - but only on 27 Sep 2013.

The "created [tag] description" activity item should probably be attributed to Community rather than to the first user to edit a tag wiki.

Comment: You're a witch!

Comment: [This apparently has happened before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110741/224428) (and was marked status-completed then), so I guess this is a regression.

Comment: :) So whats strange in it? You performed some actions, then created the account ;)

Comment: Did your account ever get merged?

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, never.

Comment: [The explanation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391569/on-the-activity-page-inconsistent-dates-are-given-for-the-creation-of-tag-wik) Kudos to @TheAmplitwist for noticing