# On the 'Activity' page, inconsistent dates are given for the creation of tag-wikis/excerpts

Tags: support, bug, tag-wiki, dates, activity

When on my profile, and going to Activity > All Actions > Posts, I can see a list of all the posts I've ever made listed in chronological order. Here, tag-wikis and tag-excerpts are also considered posts, and they show up in the list, too. The date/time of creation is also provided on the right-hand side of the page.

However, there seems to be some inconsistency in the dates given.

Here's the page on Conlang.SE.
The first seven are all correct; I did make those wikis/excerpts in late April. But the last three are wrong and appear to be random. They don't even seem to be the tag's date of creation. I don't *think* tag-synonymization is involved here.

[image]

I don't run into this problem everywhere- on [IPS](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/37503/cdr?tab=activity&sort=posts), the date shows correctly for all my tag-wiki edits; on the other hand, the dates on [EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/466641/heartspring?tab=activity), [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1278220/cdr?tab=activity&sort=posts&page=3) and [Hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/29157/cdr?tab=activity) do show up inconsistently. I didn't even have an account in 2011, but the linked pages suggest that.

- What's going on?
- Is this intended?
- Can they be made consistent? [Ideally lining up with the date I created the wiki/excerpt]

Comment: (I seem to be really bad at writing titles to my own questions, anyone who can think of a better one should feel free to edit.)

Comment: Those are  probably "default" tags, that are created when the site is created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dates seem correct to me - if they are intended to represent the date the wiki or excerpt was created, not the date of the tag itself (nor the date of *your* most recent interaction).

Keep in mind, wikis and excerpts are just specific types of posts (4 = `TagWikiExcerpt`, 5 = `TagWiki`). And wikis and excerpts are not always created in coordination with the tag - sometimes that happens years later. And they can be owned by users even if they were originally created by the community user (as is the case here).

While investigating, I first ran [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/conlang/revision/1771666/2152399/cdr-wiki-edits), which shows your posts from the activity tab, ordered by ID, and the creation dates there reflect what shows in your activity tab. The query also  indicates the last activity against the post - though the last activity might not have been by you.

Then I ran [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/conlang/query/1771666/cdr-wiki-edits), which shows that older tags have had wikis and excerpts added long after they were created, and some newer tags had those added far sooner.

But unfortunately Data Explorer can't drive this home all that well, since tag names and creation dates aren't included in the data. So I ran this query against the database, and am comfortable showing the results here because I don't think they've been excluded from SEDE due to privacy or proprietary reasons:

> [image: CDR dates for wiki/excerpt creation]

I will confess, though: I'm not sure what application logic other than the obvious might go into determining the owner of a wiki or excerpt (last who touched it owns it, but [not if it was a moderator](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/posts/1880/revisions)?). I also don't know if showing the *creation date* of the wiki or excerpt on the activity page is intended (though it is consistent with other types of posts).

So I think the only mystery here for me is - why are you reflected as the `OwnerUserId` for wikis and excerpts that you didn't create and, in some cases, others edited after you?

And now I know. From a colleague:

> It just looks weird, but if you check the timestamps of the first "revision" and the suggested edit, they're identical. The suggested edit by CDR is what created the wiki. 
> Suggested edits have to be a suggestion against *something*, so we make a blank revision to diff against.

This blank revision is owned by the community user but, in fact, the wiki or excerpt in each case was "created" by CDR, hence they are the owner. And you may notice (like I did) that the original revision appears to have been created by the community user 20 days before the edit, but in fact that was only when it was approved. [Here is the original suggested edit](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1001).

Comment: Perhaps this is related —? [According to the activity tab of my profile, I performed some actions on a site before joining](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246351)

Comment: This is a very late accept; I didn't check back here to see your edits until now. Thanks for clarifying!