# I wonder what a company cage looks like?

Tags: bug, wording, stack-overflow-developer-survey

While taking [the survey](https://www.surveymonkey.com/s/9KPHP7H) just now, I noticed this in one of the questions:

> [image]

This got me curious... what does a company cage look like? :)

Comment: I belive like a cube, just with iron bars.

Comment: Not sure if they should change it as it might invalidate existing answers.... I'd not respond to a job with a link to a company cage, but probably would if it was a company page. :D

Comment: I dunno - there is a market for that type of thing...the Internet tells me so.

Comment: I'm sure it was designed using freehand circles only.

Comment: C and P are on opposite sides of the keyboard...

Comment: @JL2210 more likely autocorrect issue which is disturbing since it means the word "cage" was used more frequently by the person writing it than "page". :D

Answer (score 19):

No no no, you obviously misread this.  *We* have a cage downstairs that we stick other companies in.
And yes, EA is in there for that whole SimCity debacle.

Comment: Is there an entrance fee for going down there and poking EA with a pointy stick through the bars?

Comment: So, do you have a link to that Stack Overflow Careers Company Cage?

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby We're pretty much doing that at all times, we have radios and Christmas music is readily available at the moment.  Oh yeah, I said it.

Comment: Wait, do you mean you are playing christmas music like "Last Christmas" to EA? I'm sure that's covered by the Geneva convention somehow, I mean, that's inmorale and inhuman...even when it comes to EA...anyway, can we join?

Comment: @JoachimSauer No one goes to the basement! However, you [can see the upstairs here](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!data=!1m8!1m3!1d3!2d-74.006579!3d40.708659!2m2!1f142.12!2f86.03!4f75!2m9!1e1!2m4!1sd8njc0EiDMgAAAQIt-NMmA!2e0!9m1!6sTertius+Carstens+-+Carstens360+Business+Photos!5m2!1sd8njc0EiDMgAAAQIt-NMmA!2e0!4m12!2m11!1m10!1s0x0%3A0xf9742bc540e39399!3m8!1m3!1d3024!2d-74.006731!3d40.708762!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1&fid=5) (there's a downtairs too, where the dev offices are, but I can't figure out how to get there at the moment :-/)

Comment: Oh hey I found it, [here's the downstairs](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!data=!1m8!1m3!1d3!2d-74.006616!3d40.708464!2m2!1f15.51!2f72.34!4f75!2m11!1e1!2m5!1sDu6WHJ5-nGMAAAQIt-PpTg!2e0!7e2!9m1!6sTertius+Carstens+-+Carstens360+Business+Photos!5m3!1sDu6WHJ5-nGMAAAQIt-PpTg!2e0!3e2&fid=5)

Comment: @NickCraver: nice! But I'm somewhat worried that your [upvote- and downvote storage](https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=40.708709%2C-74.00679200000002&cbp=%2C249.17%2C%2C0%2C17.39&layer=c&panoid=7y0eMsPaFwwAAAQIt-PpPg&spn=0.18000000000000788%2C0.30000000000001953&output=classic&cbll=40.708709%2C-74.006792) are very close to each other! Aren't you worried about the two mixing and leading to annihilation?

Comment: @JoachimSauer nah we're not worried, as we gather more votes the chance of *total* annihilation is pretty much a sure thing.  No sense in worrying about something you won't be around to clean up, that's our motto!

Comment: Awesome, never thought to take such a virtual tour in your office! I didn't find the Cage, but I did figure where you host your IIS: http://i.stack.imgur.com/105WR.png BTW love the "Skeet Emulator" idea. ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Imagine saying to an intern: "The IIS is done, can you remove the platters from it?" - "...yeah, sure..." - ... - "Wait, why is our website down?!"

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby that's a stroke of genius!

Comment: hehe, think you forgot to mark this [tag:status-completed]? :)