# Login Page got a zombie slash (when not logged in)

Tags: bug, status-completed, login

I see this in the [login page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/login), when not logged in already:

> [image]

This slash should not be there...

Resolution: 1366
Firefox: 40.0.3

Also reproduced on Chrome 45

Comment: Really no need for whole screen and your email, just to show this little thing. Uploaded a better screenshot. :)

Comment: I'm sorry for large picture.

Comment: Zombie slash time!

Comment: lol, some good old meta humor. :-D

Comment: Bug of Teh day. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whoops. A stray slash snuck out earlier today. Thanks for spotting it and helping us return it back to where it belongs.

Comment: [Cage](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212583/i-wonder-what-a-company-cage-looks-like), perhaps? :-)

Comment: Slash was(?) good zombie ninja.